# SAS Proc Sgplot and Floating Point Overflow

Tags: sas

I'm trying to produce histogram graphs in SAS for different product types. SAS produced graphs for all the other product types besides one (let's call it A), and the error message I got is

ERROR: Floating Point Overflow.
ERROR: Termination due to Floating Point Exception

I'm not sure why this is happening and was wondering if anyone has any ideas to fix it. Many thanks!

```
proc sgplot data=output.base;
xaxis values=(0 to 50 by 5);
title "Distribution - Product A +";
histogram fare_distance_in_km;
where product_type = "Product A +" & fare_distance_in_km<=50 & disgroup^="missing";
run;
```

Comment: It's somewhat hard to say without the data you used to produce this, or some dataset that produces the same error.  Is it reproducible?  Is anything special about that product type (large number of values, for example)?  Unusual distribution?

Comment: Hi Joe, the entire data set is indeed very big - it's 350 GB. But what puzzles me is that if other product types worked out fine, Product A should not have any issue either. I also performed other statistical analysis on all the products (such as proc means procedure) and there is no issue for Product A.

Comment: Could just be a bug in the proc, I suppose - maybe with such big buckets you are larger than they really tested things on.  I'd probably start a ticket with SAS tech support (support.sas.com) and see what they say - then come back here and post the answer.

Comment: Try simulating a similar dataset (similar number of obs, similar range of values, etc) and see if you can replicate the problem. Try taking using (obs=) option to limit the number of one read, and see if the error is related to number of records.

Comment: Thank you guys for the advice! I tried to limit the number of observations to read by adding more restrictions (such as limiting the analysis only to products over a certain price threshold), and my codes eventually worked. Therefore, I suppose the error is related to number of records and the original data set is a bit too large for SAS to handle.

Comment: Does it include any traceback information? It should be able to handle the size without a problem unless you run out of memory, or if you are using a 32-bit machine. I'd recommend sending SAS tech support the error to let them know as well.